# JavaFX8 Timeline playing issue

Tags: javafx-8

I am using multiple Timelines in my application as

```
Timeline timeLine1 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), actionEvent -> {
        System.out.println("Enter in timer for check and playcontent");
        MaintainPlaybackArray.checkAndPlayContent();
    }));
    timeLine1.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeLine1.play();
```

Which will play each seconds

```
Timeline timeLine2 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), actionEvent -> {
        System.out.println("Enter in timer");
        getSchedule();
        checkSchedule();
    }));
    System.out.println("after timer");
    timeLine2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeLine2.play();
```

Which Calls every 5 Seconds

```
Timeline timeLine3 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), actionEvent -> {
        System.out.println("in timer");
        String currentChecksum = Util.md5(getScheduleJsonArray().toJSONString());
        if (currentChecksum != null && !currentChecksum.equalsIgnoreCase(checksum)) {
            System.out.println("Schedule changed");
            isScheduleChanged = true;
            checksum = currentChecksum;
        }
    }));
    System.out.println("after timer");
    timeLine3.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeLine3.play();
```

which will executes after each 10 second.

### Problem

> When i execute the application after starting all the timelines it cannot play in synchronous manner.
>
> i.e:
>   timLine1 will not executes for 8 seconds and then suddenly it executes 8 times at a time.
>    timeline2 will execute any time like after 8 seconds or twice after 12 seconds. 
>   timeLine3 will executes after 12 seconds or 15 seconds.

So, Please help so that i can execute the code in synchronous manner.
is there anything i can use instead of Timeline?

Comment: your timeline should be executed simultaneously, most probably operations you are using in handlers are long or network dependent, thus timeline stuck in them and it looks like stuttering.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Can you please suggest me any alternative of this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ParallelTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html) or [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) depending on your needs.